# error “The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.” displayed after installng phpmyadmin

Tags: apache-2.4, phpmyadmin, json, php7

Installed phpmyadmin and tried to access http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin, but error displayed in my browser

error : " `The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`"

My configuration:

```
PHP 7.0.7 (cli)
Apache/2.4.6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

I tried to add `json.so` file under folder `/etc/php.d/` and also added entries in `/etc/php.ini "extension=json.so"` but the error still persists.

Comment: You need to install php-json. You didn't detail how you installed PHP but `yum install php-json` should work. Make sure you reload Apache after this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment . I tried yum install php-json, there is a dependency error "Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64" . I installed php via yum.

Comment: I assumed you're using the standard repo - in this case, I think you need to do yum install php70u-json as it seems you installed PHP from an alternate repo.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: will do it but how to do that . I am new to these things

Comment: On my answer below which I added you just need to click on the arrow pointing up and then you'll get a solid green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you're using the standard repo - in this case, I think you need to do yum install php70u-json as it seems you installed PHP from an alternate repo.